# Application of "twice the integral" even if the function is not graphically even?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If the graph of a function is not even, but still you get the same result for both limits can one use "twice the integral"? e.g. I have y=x^(2/3) with x from -1 to 1 and if I'm trying to determine the length of this curve using arc length integral formula can I do the following:

$$\begin{align}
S&=\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{2}{3x^{1/3}}\right)^2}dx\\
&=\frac13\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{9x^{2/3}+4}}{\left|x^{1/3}\right|}dx\\
&=\frac23\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{9x^{2/3}+4}}{\left|x^{1/3}\right|}dx
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong that this function is not even.

$$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{2}{3x^{1/3}}\right)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{9x^{2/3}+4}}{3\left|x^{1/3}\right|}$$

The absolute value in the denominator is crucial. Without it, we get:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{9x^{2/3}+4}}{x^{1/3}}\,dx = 0,$$ if the integral exists (it's an "improper integral,") since this function is odd.

But with an absolute value in the denominator, the function is even.